# Is there any difference between java.util.Deque and java.util.ArrayDeque

Tags: java

Why there're two Deque in java liblary?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html

Comment: `Deque` is Interface, `ArrayDeque` implements `Deque`.

Comment: Just like `List` and `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayDeque` is a class. `Deque` is an interface.
`ArrayDeque` implements the `Deque` interface.

An interface is like a contract that defines what a class that implemets it should do(generally with the method signatures) , but does not define how therefore you cannot instantiate an object of an interface. However, you can implement the interface with a class, but that class must implement all methods of the interface (unless its an abstract class).
Anyway, you should read more about classes and interfaces.

Comment: You can instantiate an interface but you have to provide implementations for the non-default methods inside

Comment: @S.Tushinov In that case you are instantiating an anonymous class that implements the interface. You're not instantiating the interface.

Comment: @Janus Varmarken read about it and you're right. Sorry on my part, good to learn something new.